# Styling with hidden overflow elements

Tags: css

I am trying to create a section on my page that will contain inline-block divs (that would of various lengths). This outer div will be scales with the width of its parent (the parent has col-md-8). I'm trying to see if it's possible to float all the inner individual divs left with a right margin and have them disappear off to the right edge of the parent div. Clearly I'm missing something as these are not lining up the way I want them to.

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 330px;
  height: 140px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  height: 130px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.box-1-col {
  width: 130px;
}

.box-2-col {
  width: 260px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="outer clearfix">
        <div id="box-1" class="box box-2-col">
          This is box 1
        </div>
        <div id="box-2" class="box box-1-col">
          This is box 2
        </div>
        <div id="box-3" class="box box-1-col">
          This is box 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xc66s1L8/4/

Comment: Is this hat you look for ? https://jsfiddle.net/xc66s1L8/10/ If yes, do not use float but inline-block and white-space in this example or flex and overflow in this other example https://jsfiddle.net/xc66s1L8/16/

Comment: Both of them will do, thank you!